# Differences between repositories methods creation

Tags: c#, repository

Someone can tell me the difference between:

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>();
```

and

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
```

What is the `<T>` after GetAll???

Answer (score 2):

Well that makes a lot more sense. Please use code tags.

`<T>` is used to indicate a generic parameter, you can add any type to it (provided you don't violate any constraints, ofcourse).

Example:

```
var result1 = GetAll<string>();
var result2 = GetAll<int>();
```

Both will use the first method.

If you want to use the second, use

```
var result = GetAll();
```

[MSDN on generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

One reason why you could want this is this sample implementation:

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>() {
    return someDataContext.Users.OfType<T>();
}
```

called with

```
var managers = GetAll<Manager>();
```

Working sample:

```
void Main()
{
    printTypes<string>();
}

static void printTypes<T>() {
    var myList = new List<Object> {"string 1", "string 2", 5 };
    foreach(var item in myList.OfType<T>()) {
        Console.WriteLine (item);
    }
}
```

Output

> string 1
>   string 2

Comment: I'm using it in a repository, so, can i just use getAll(), with no generic type like getAll<T>()???

Answer (score 0):

Both:

`IQueryable<T> GetAll<T>();`

and

`IQueryable<T> GetAll();`

make use of [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

- `GetAll<T>`: The `<T>` in `GetAll<T>` is a generic method.  `T` has
  method level scope.
- `GetAll()`: a non-generic method that returns a class level generic `IQueryable<T>`

`GetAll` is not a .NET framework method.  Rather a custom definition in your repository code.  Without the implementation of both methods no one can tell you which one to use for some given scenario. That being said, I expect a well written implementation to be interchangeable.  If I had to guess, `GetAll()` may function as a stand in for generic type inference for a method without a parameter of type `T`. Then the caller can make a parameterless call to `GetAll` without specifying the type `GetAll<Entity>` per-se.